# remove some part of href

Tags: javascript, inline, href

I have a link like this

```
myaccount.php?posted=true&save=true
```

and I wanted to remove the `save=true` when clicking the other link, so the remainder will be

```
myaccount.php?posted=true
```

NOTE that `myaccount.php?posted=true&save=true` must not put any `#`

And the link need to remove `save=true` must not load because I have a javascript running.

Comment: It's not quite clear if you have 2 links, or at what moment you need to remove the `&save=true`

Comment: Your question is confusing ? How do you identify the link to replace ?

Comment: Worth looking! [URI.js]http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/ URI.js is a javascript library for working with URLs.

Answer (score 2):

For an anchor like:

```
<a id="yourId" href="myaccount.php?posted=true&save=true">Your link</a>
```

You could use the following javascript:

```
var link = document.getElementById('yourId');
link.href = link.href.replace(/&save=true/, '');
```

Comment: is "link" an element name? sorry newbie here

Comment: @IvorySantos Updated answer with more details

Comment: I think that's not the right way. The current page have save=true, and I wanted that when I click another link, the save=true will be removed. and page must not reload

Answer (score -2):

If you are using jQuery:

```
$('anchor-to-click').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefalut(); //stop page loading
    this.href = this.href.replace(/&?save=true/, "");
});
```